# How to use addExtraLib in Monaco with an external type definition

Tags: monaco-editor

I can see how to use `addExtraLib` in Monaco to add an ambient declaration file. What's not clear is how to use this function with an external declaration file so that Typescript code in the editor can do a:

```js
import * as External from "external" 
    
External.foo();
```

On the Monaco set-up side, this doesn't seem to work:

```js
 // compiler options
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2016,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    moduleResolution: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
    module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
    noEmit: true,
    noLib: true,
    typeRoots: ["node_modules/@types"]
});

// extra libraries
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
    'export declare function foo():string;', 'node_modules/@types/external/index.d.ts');

monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    noSemanticValidation: false,
    noSyntaxValidation: false
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After playing around a little I found a solution. Basically, the file has to be loaded using `createModel` with an explicit file URL. If you do this then the relative file path for `node_module/@types` works. Here's my working solution that can be used in the playground:

```js
// compiler options
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2016,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    moduleResolution: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
    module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
    noEmit: true,
    typeRoots: ["node_modules/@types"]
});

// extra libraries
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
    `export declare function next() : string`,
    'node_modules/@types/external/index.d.ts');

monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    noSemanticValidation: false,
    noSyntaxValidation: false
})

var jsCode = `import * as x from "external"
    const tt : string = x.dnext();`;

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    model: monaco.editor.createModel(jsCode,"typescript",new monaco.Uri("file:///main.tsx")), 
});
```

Comment: I want to add lodash. I can add a file path but what to write in the file content? I'm totally unaware of the file content thing

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar Probably coming too late but you can check that out [here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-javascript-defaults).

Comment: What is the second argument to `addExtraLib` though? Also, browsers don't load things from `file:///`, so what context does this answer apply to? Is this Electron?

Answer (score 14):

Joe's answer didn't work for me, fixed by prefixing the external type definition file path with `file:///`

Here's an updated example for the [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html):

```js
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
    'export declare function add(a: number, b: number): number',
    'file:///node_modules/@types/math/index.d.ts'
);

const model = monaco.editor.createModel(
    `import {add} from 'math';\nconst x = add(3, 5);\n`,
    'typescript',
    monaco.Uri.parse('file:///main.tsx')
);

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {model});
```

It's not necessary to provide the compiler options and diagnostic options.

Answer (score 8):

As of April 2021 (`monaco-editor@0.23.0`), I wasn't able to get either of the prior solutions working without some additional details based on [monaco-editor#2295](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2295), [monaco-editor#1839](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1839), and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63349650. My use case required making type definitions available from several existing NPM packages (not just arbitrary paths to files) and this may have affected the solution. To summarize, I needed to:

1. Bundle *all* of the `.d.ts` files from each package into a single file. TypeScript [doesn't make this easy](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4433), and so instead I used [dts-bundle-generator](https://github.com/timocov/dts-bundle-generator), but other solutions exist.
2. Import the `.d.ts` content for each package using [raw-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) or other plain-text loading alternatives.
3. Call `addExtraLib` with the source for each module, *adding an explicit `declare module 'module-name'` to the source code*.

Full example below:

```js
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';

import source1 from '!!raw-loader!./types/package-one.d.ts';
import source2 from '!!raw-loader!./types/package-two.d.ts'

monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
  `declare module '@my-project/package-one' { ${source1} }`,
  'file:///node_modules/@my-project/package-one/index.d.ts' // irrelevant?
);
monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
  `declare module '@my-project/package-two' { ${source2} }`,
  'file:///node_modules/@my-project/package-two/index.d.ts' // irrelevant?
);

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('root'), {
    value: `
import { Foo } from '@my-project/package-one';

const foo = new Foo();
`,
    language: 'typescript',
    theme: 'vs-dark'
});
```

Comment: Try adding the `esModule=false` option to avoid having to declare modules: `const typings = require("!!raw-loader?esModule=false!./debugger-runtime.d.ts");` And yes, the lines marked `irrelevant` are indeed irrelevant.

Comment: And I did not bundle my typings files. I add multiple files in my React application, each just loading them with the require call from above.

Comment: Each of the packages referenced in my project contains dozens of typings files. Without a real `package.json` pointing to the `types` root, without using ES module imports, and without any reference to the real name of the package, I'm not sure how Monaco would be able to resolve imports of the package name?