# Provide autocompletion in Monaco using .d.ts files generated from jsdoc

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc, monaco-editor

I'm building a website where users write javascript code inside an instance of Monaco editor.
I provide them some custom js libraries and I want to also provide auto completion for those libraries.

My custom libraries are written in javascript and annotated using jsdoc, so I'm using the typescript compiler to generate `.d.ts` files. This is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "include": ["src/**/*.js"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2015",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "outDir": "docs/",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
```

When I run `npx tsc` on this simple javascript file

```js
import { a } from './v0/JsA';
import { b } from './v0/JsB';

export const myLib = { a, b }
```

I obtain .d.ts files like the following

```
// myLib.d.ts
export namespace myLib {
    export { a };
    export { b };
}
import { a } from "./v0/JsA";
import { b } from "./v0/JsB";
```

that I provide to Monaco using

```js
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(dtsFileContentAsString, '')
```

Unfortunately this does not trigger autocompletion in Monaco when I start writing `myLib.`.

However I found out that manually changing the content of `myLib.d.ts` file to

```
declare namespace myLib {
    let x = a;
    let y = b;
}
import { a } from "./v0/JsA";
import { b } from "./v0/JsB";
```

does trigger auto completion.

Any help to make this work? (either on the monaco side or the typescript compiler side)

Answer (score -1):

I have found the library dts-bundle to be useful in this context
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dts-bundle#command-line

Also bundles multiple .d.ts files to a single file to be used by monaco editor

Comment: Useful _how_? Because its README.md does not explain how to actually get the typing into monaco-editor.

Comment: it allows bundling all type definition files into one file that can then be used. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66948535