# Monaco Editor React import typescript types

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor, react-monaco-editor

I have a monaco editor react instance running in the browser.

I would like to import the material UI packages in, so I have access to the types in the browser editor.  (@mui/material)

I imagine it is using by setExtraLib, but I am unsure how to structure it.

How would I do this import?

Comment: This thread seems to be similar to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058191/how-to-use-addextralib-in-monaco-with-an-external-type-definition